# Correlated Random walk using simple Python if conditions

Tags: python, random

I am trying to make a correlated random walker using pythons if conditions. The walker is supposed to tend to move in the same direction with the correlation coefficient of a. I am not sure if what I get is correct or not. This is my code. I want to give 50 steps and 1000 trajectories.

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def RW_1D(n,N):

    X = np.zeros((n,N))
    
    T = np.linspace(1, n,n)

    for j in range(N):   
        xnow = 0     
  
        x0_direction = np.random.rand()

        if x0_direction <= 0.5:
                xnew = xnow+1
        elif x0_direction > 0.5:
                xnew= xnow-1

        X[0,j] = xnew

        for i in range(n-1):
            a = 0.7
            b = 0.3 
            step = np.random.rand()
            if xnew > xnow and step < a:
                xnew1 = xnew+1
            elif xnew < xnow and step > a:
                xnew1 = xnew+1
            else: 
                xnew1 = xnew-1

            xnow = xnew
            xnew = xnew1
            X[i+1,j]= xnew

    return X, T 


X, T = RW_1D(50,1000)```


I expect to get a normalized histogram with two picks, but did not get that.
````

Comment: might help if you explained what it should do for different coefficients.  e.g. for `a = 1.` should it walk in a straight line following some initial trajectory? what about `a = 0.` or `a = -1.`?  I'm assuming intermediate values would be obvious from those cases!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the conditions for a and b are ( 0<a,b<1) and that a+b =1. This is to provide the correlation. a provides that the walker keeps the movement in the forward direction and be provides that the walker's movement in backward to the current direction of movement.